# jQuery accordian with closed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'm trying to present an jQuery accordion that is closed initially. Right now, it when you open the page, the first tab opens and I'd like it to be closed by default and opened when a tab is clicked.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
<style>
#accordion {
list-style: none;
margin: 30px 0;
padding: 0;
height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #7d8d96;
width:960px;}

#accordion li {
float: left;
border-left:
display: block;
height: 170px;
width: 50px;
padding: 15px 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5em;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;}

#accordion li img {
border: none;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
float: left;
margin: -15px 15px 0 0;
}

#accordion li.active {
width: 450px;
}
</style>

<ul id="accordion">
  <li>
    <img src="images/section_1.png" />
    <strong>Section 1 Header</strong><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/section_2.png" />
    <strong>Section 2 Header</strong><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/section_3.png" />
    <strong>Section 3 Header</strong><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/section_4.png" />
    <strong>Section 4 Header</strong><br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In iaculis volutpat quam, non suscipit arcu accumsan at. Aliquam pellentesque.
</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


activeItem = $("#accordion li:first");
$(activeItem).addClass('active');

$("#accordion li").click(function(){
    $(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
    $(this).animate({width: "450px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
    activeItem = this;
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't removing `$(activeItem).addClass('active')` do it?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm thinking that line just adds the class "active" to opened tabs. I was wondering if I had to add a line to tell it to stay closed until it was prompted to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your selector depend on a variable `activeItem`, you just need to define it first, and don't need to add class `active` to that first element.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var activeItem;
$("#accordion li").click(function(){
    $(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
    $(this).animate({width: "450px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
    activeItem = this;
});
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v3YTY/1/)**

**EDIT:**
(to open and close)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var activeItem;
    $("#accordion li").click(function(){
        if(activeItem == this){
            $(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
             activeItem = '';
        }else{ 
            $(activeItem).animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
            $(this).animate({width: "450px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});
            activeItem = this;
        } 
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ye47n/1/)**

Comment: This is fantastic! Is there a way to close the active item and collapse it to the default state?

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, use this `$("#accordion li").animate({width: "50px"}, {duration:300, queue:false});` - you are not using jQuery's accordion functionality, you are doing a custom animation, so you need to use it on all `#accordion li` to get it back to normal `with`

Comment: I'm sorry Sergio it's not collapsing back. I'm putting that line right under the $(document).ready(function(){ line. Is this correct?

Comment: Ah I see what you did. Is there anyway to use that same button's functionality by clicking one of the tabs instead?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on my side. I wish I knew more JavaScript to help develop this custom part. It's not opening or closing.

Comment: THANKS! That was it, just checked the edited demo. Thanks for all of your help, Sergio!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: false });
}
```

The option active set the active "panel" of the accordion if(false) no "panel" are active.

Then on click of a panel the "active" option will be set to this "panel" index.